# SwiftLint analyzer removes imports if using of static calls (not desired behavior)

Tags: swift, swiftlint

In my project I use a SwiftLint analyzer, in order to remove all unused imports I use these lines

```
xcodebuild -workspace lintanalize.xcworkspace -scheme MY_SCHEME -configuration Debug > xcodebuild.log
swiftlint analyze --fix --compiler-log-path xcodebuild.log
```

It really works and the analyzer knows how to remove unused imports, however, the problem is that it wrongly removes those imports where only static calls, for example:

```
import PhotosUI

class PermissionPhotos {
    func request(_ callback: @escaping (PermissionStatus) -> Void) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { ... }
    }
}
```

In the example I use `PHPhotoLibrary` static method call `requestAuthorization`, so the analyzer will remove `import PhotosUI` as it thinks that the static call is not using this import

Is there a way to fix it?

***UPD***

I also noticed that the same behavior related to the params, for example

```
import PhotosUI

class PermissionPhotos {
    func request(myvalue: PHPhotoLibrary) { ... }
}
```

In this case, `PHPhotoLibrary` uses as a param, so the analyzer will miss this and will remove `import PhotosUI`, looks like the analyzer see only the actual definition of objects like

```
let myobj = PHPhotoLibrary()
```

Comment: Have you tried this configuration: https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/unused_import.html

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov it is not obvious, what do you mean by `this` configuration?

Comment: Do you have any yaml file associated with your project which define the rules?

Comment: @GaneshSomani, sure it won't work without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `swiftlint.yml` file can be used to make some rule bending modifications / customizations. Refer this page for rules related to unused imports - https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/unused_import.html and check the section `Default configuration`

My best bet is you should turn on `require_explicit_imports`.

Comment: oh, looks like it really works, however, I am excited if you possibly know where I can find a description of all the sub-properties? I mean in the documentation it is mentioned `require_explicit_imports`, but there is no description of what exactly it does?

Comment: Unfortunately even I could not find the complete documentation, hence I could only present this answer as a suggestion.